# Extruding curve and editing non destructively

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves, extrude

How would the following be possible using Blender? The example image is from Cinema 4D where this is easy. The shape is made with one spline of which two instances are made and set as children for the extrude modifier.

I have a curve, which is extruded into two different parts. The two parts are mainly needed because I need to different textures for the different surfaces ("Top" and "Side" in the example).

I tried to use the curve's bevel/extrude options in Blender and can get about this shape, while still maintaining the object as a curve (ie. not transforming to mesh). But how can I apply different textures to the different sides?

The main point of this exercise is to keep the curve editable, so that the extrusions follow the editing (if I convert to a mesh I can't easily change the shape of the curve for the surfaces afterwards).

[image: afterwar]

Comment: Related : [Can a curve with a bevel profile have 2 materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/119316/78972)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can directly assign two different textures to a curve.
But as a workaround, you can use a *Gradient texture*.

I'm just mixing two colors, but you can mix any number of shaders/textures...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Might be usefull. But I forgot to add that I need to export the project to unity and hope that it works there also... (Using glTF export)

Comment: Hello :). Why not convert it into a mesh, right before exporting? It's easy to add multiple textures to a mesh.

Comment: I need to be able to edit it after the export, multiple times. Make the spline longer with new "peaks/valleys" and edit the height of the existing ones etc, so that the editing is "smooth" like with a bezier curve. It would be quite tedious to always have to change to mesh and assign textures and uv-map and what have you, then export, then revert to curve again etc...

Comment: BTW, how did you make that shape? I'm having difficulty making straight edges with bezier curves, and to get the bevel profile curve to align correctly with the "main" curve.

Comment: Hey :). *Curve > Set Spline Type > Poly*. Feel free to post new questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for this. I marked this as answered as it is the closest to what I'm trying to do. Everything worked find except unity didn't show both textures, will figure out something. Maybe baking the texture or something...

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.